# How to add pagination templates in the links with spring-data 1.11

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am trying to upgrade to spring boot 1.3.1 which ship with spring-data-commons 1.11.2.
It appears that except for the root endpoint, the pagination templates are gone.
For example with this example project: https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks

When hitting http://localhost:8080/ I get:

```
    "restbucks:orders": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders{?page,size,sort,projection}",
        "templated": true,
        "title": "Access or create orders"
    }
```

So that includes the page, size and sort parameters.

But when hitting http://localhost:8080/orders I get:

```
"_links": {
     ...
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders"
    }
},
```

With spring boot 1.2.x, I would have got:

```
"_links": {
     ...
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/orders{?page,size,sort,projection}",
        "templated": true
    }
},
```

In my project, I also manually add the pagination for some custom resources by using the [PagedResourcesAssembler.appendPaginationParameterTemplates](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/01f2c30b1d1c342e168b3b541974332cc429e3e2/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/web/PagedResourcesAssembler.java#L167) but this method has been deprecated and doesn't add the template anymore.

My client side library won't add the pagination parameters if the URL is not defined as templated, so this is preventing me from upgrading.

Comment: as the deprecation notice states `@deprecated this method will be removed in 1.11 as no Spring Data module actually calls it. Other clients calling it should stop doing so as {@link Link}s used for pagination shouldn't be templated in the first place.` they removed it for a reason. Anyways, are you using the same code as the github repository? (without the `Pageable` param)

Comment: take a look at Spring Data REST [reference for paging and sorting](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting)

Comment: Yeah they did it on purpose apparently but I can't think of a good reason for it. Isn't the point of HATEOAS to document as much as you can in the response?
I am not sure what you mean by "without the Pageable param" but yeah my code is similar.
Regarding the doc you linked, it is actually not in conformance with what the code actually does. The template parameters are there: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting

Comment: take a look at the signature of the method in the repository interface on the reference documentation `public Page findByNameStartsWith(@Param("name") String name, Pageable p);`, thats what i meant with `Pageable` parameter, sorry if i wasn't very clear.